# Loop List Python for Variable

Tags: python, json, rest

Im trying to loop through a list and insert the 'extensionid' into the URL

```
extensionid = ['1234','12356']
url = '/restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension/'+extensionid+'/presence'

params = {

    'dndStatus': "TakeAllCalls",

}

resp = platform.get(url, params,)
print ((resp.text()))
```

But I get the error

> url = '/restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension/'+extensionid+'/presence'
>   TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str [Finished in
>   1.121s

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: what do you expect your `url` to look like?

Comment: you should use a package to construct urls rather then sticking them together by hand. Mistakes are easy

Comment: also extensionid is a list and you can't interpolate like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need.

```
extensionid = ['1234','12356']
url = '/restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension/{}/presence'

params = {
    'dndStatus': "TakeAllCalls",
}

for id in extensionid:     #iterate each id
    resp = platform.get(url.format(id), params)  #form URL and query. 
    print ((resp.text()))
```

Answer (score 0):

extensionid is a list of strings.
So, you cannot concatenate a list with a string as error is telling you.

To access a specific item of the list you have to use an index.

For example:

```
extensionid[0] // it contains 1234
extensionid[1] // it contains 12356
```

So, your url can be written like this:

```
url = '/restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension/'+extensionid[0]+'/presence'
```

In this case it will be evaluated by python as:

```
url = '/restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension/1234/presence'
```

Please consider this simple documentation about lists:

https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list

To iterate the elements of a list you can use:

```
for element in extensionid:
    url='/restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension/'+ element +'/presence'
    print(url)
```

Comment: it's good to read the official documentation, using `str.format` is a better way

Comment: I was not focusing on the solution only but on the problem itself trying to explain why he got the error, understanding it and avoiding to have it in the future...